# How can I fire component specific events from within a class in a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to integrate [Fine Uploader](https://fineuploader.com/) in my project which is built on Laravel & Vue. This project has a lot of legacy code that I have to support (such as old CSS classes, etc.) so I need to integrate Fine Uploader as a JS plugin, and can't use any [existing 3rd party Vue Fine Uploader components](https://github.com/FineUploader/vue-fineuploader) that may be out there.

I've managed to get it to work for the most part. However, here is the challenge that I present to you. Below, you can see a screenshot of my code, in which I am instantiating the Fine Uploader instance inside my mounted hook.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see I have highlighted the part of the code where I would emit an event when a new file is submitted for uploading. Here however, since I am inside the Fine Uploader instance, when I do this.$emit, it doesn't work (as it shouldn't).

I tried to circumvent this by using a global eventBus. This worked, but created issues when several files are dropped into the uploader at once. The event fires multiple times and often loses track of which event was fired by which instance, thus causing the 'thumbnails component' to perform duplicate actions.

I am convinced that I need to fire 'component-specific' events so that the thumbnail components that are generated and updated (onProgress and onComplete) only take their relevant actions once.

How can I fire component specific events from within another class instantiation?

Thank you.

Comment: By `doesn't work`, do you mean `$emit` doesn't exist in `this` within `onSubmitted`?

Comment: Correct, that's the error I would get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function callbacks don't have their contexts bound, so `this` inside the callback does not refer to the Vue instance (which would result in `$emit` being `undefined`).

There are a few different solutions:

- Use an [arrow-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

  ```
  onSubmitted: (id, name) => {
    // `this` is Vue instance
  }
  ```
- Bind the function context with [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

  ```
  onSubmitted: function(id, name) {
     // `this` is Vue instance
  }.bind(this)
  ```
- Use a cached reference to the Vue instance:

  ```
  const vm = this;
  const f = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    // ...
    onSubmitted: function(id, name) {
       vm.$emit(...)
    }
  })
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Personally, I find the first option to be the cleanest and preferred it in my implementation. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kopty No problem :) Agreed!

Comment: Update for those interested: I ended up using method #3, because later on in my code, there were functions in the FineUploaderBasic object that I was utilizing with commands like "this.getUuid(photo)", and those wouldn't work because it would refer to the Vue component when calling 'this' once it was bound that way in options 1 & 2. Many ways to skin a cat. Thanks tony19 for providing various ways to do this.